# firebird user with granted privileges cannot access tables

Tags: firebird, roles, privileges, jaybird

I created a Firebird user (PIPPO) via jaybird, follows gsec "display":

```
GSEC> di
     user name                    uid   gid admin     full name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYSDBA                              0     0           Sql Server Administrator
PIPPO                               0     0           GesAll 1.0 User
GSEC>
```

I create a role (GESALLDB_USER) in Firebird DB and granted some privileges:

```
SQL> show grant;

/* Grant permissions for this database */
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON ANELLI TO ROLE GESALLDB_USER

GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON COPPIE TO ROLE GESALLDB_USER

GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON COVE TO ROLE GESALLDB_USER
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON DATI_CONFIGURAZIONE TO ROLE GESALLDB_USER
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON DATI_COVE TO ROLE GESALLDB_USER
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON DATI_SOGGETTI TO ROLE GESALLDB_USER
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON DEPOSIZIONI TO ROLE GESALLDB_USER
GRANT GESALLDB_USER TO PIPPO
SQL>
```

I granted this role to the new user via jaybird (last line before):

The problem is that whenever I try to run a query, I get the message:

```
SQL> select * from anelli;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 28000
no permission for read/select access to TABLE ANELLI
SQL>
```

If I grant directly the TABLE to the newly created user everything works.

```
SQL> grant all on anelli to pippo;
SQL> show grant;

/* Grant permissions for this database */
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON ANELLI TO ROLE GESALLDB_USER

GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON ANELLI TO USER PIPPO

SQL> connect "C:\Users\teiluke\Documents\Ondulati\DB\prova\gesalldb.fdb" user "p
ippo" password "topolino";
Commit current transaction (y/n)?y
Committing.
Server version:
WI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5
WI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5/XNet (E7441EA1CA2CF4)/P12
WI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5/XNet (E7441EA1CA2CF4)/P12
Database:  "C:\Users\teiluke\Documents\Ondulati\DB\prova\gesalldb.fdb", User: pi
ppo
SQL> select * from anelli;
```

```
 PROGRESSIVO FEDERAZIONE RNA    TIPO   ANNO         INIZIO         FINE ATTIVA
  LAST_USED
============ =========== ====== ====== ====== ============ ============ ====== =
===========
           1 FOI         89LR   E      2012              1          100 N
          0
           2 FOI         89LR   E      2013              1          100 S
         41
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Firebird 3.0 and earlier the rights assigned to a role are only applied when that role is specified when connecting to the database. In other words if a user has a role, that user does not automatically get the rights of that role. The user needs to explicitly indicate the role to use, otherwise only the rights assigned to `PUBLIC` and the user itself apply.

For ISQL the [`CONNECT` specification](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-connect-database) is:

```
CONNECT database name [user username] [password password] [role role_name];
```

So for your specific example use:

```
SQL> connect "C:\Users\teiluke\Documents\Ondulati\DB\prova\gesalldb.fdb" user "p
ippo" password "topolino" role GESALLDB_USER;
```

Role names surrounded by (single or double) quotes are treated case sensitive. So using `role 'gesalldb_user'` will not match a role `GESALLDB_USER`, while `role gesalldb_user` will. This is like the rules for other double quoted objectnames (like table and columnnames) in Firebird.

This also applies when using a driver or access component, but the exact configuration and property name might vary (eg for Jaybird the property is `roleName` or `sqlRole`).

In Firebird 4.0 and later, you can grant a role as a ["default role"](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-security-grant-role-default). Privileges of default roles are automatically applied even when the role is not explicitly specified on connect.

Comment: Done as suggested same result:
'SQL> connect "c:\users\teiluke\documents\ondulati\DB\prova\gesalldb.fdb" user "pippo" password "topolino" role "gesalldb_user";
Server version:
WI-V2.5.2.26540 Firebird 2.5
Database:  "c:\users\teiluke\documents\ondulati\db\prova\gesalldb.fdb", User: pippo, Role: gesalldb_user
SQL> select * from anelli;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 28000
no permission for read/select access to TABLE ANELLI
SQL> show grant;
/* Grant permissions for this database */
.
.
.
GRANT GESALLDB_USER TO PIPPO'

Comment: @GianlucaPasqualato Weird, I will try to reproduce this and see if I missed anything.

Comment: @GianlucaPasqualato I just tested it, and the role is case sensitive when surrounded by (single or double) quotes, so using `role 'gesalldb_user'` doesn't work, but using `role 'GESALLDB_USER'` or `role gesalldb_user` will work.

Comment: thanks again, it works if I run it directly from isql.
If I do it with jaybird:
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", utenteDB);
props.setProperty("password", passDB);
props.setProperty("role", roleDB);
I printed out roleDB and its valuse is GESALLDB_USER
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:" + DB_path,props);
I got:
Errore: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544352. no permission for read/select access to TABLE <table>

Comment: For Jaybird the property is `roleName` (and `sqlRole` as alias), see the [list of connection properties](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.3/release_notes.html#__RefHeading__2785_1560579136)